# Derive the Cramer-Rao lower bound (CRLB) for the variance of any unbiased for estimator of $\lambda$ for random sample from Poisson ($\lambda$)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be a random sample from Poisson ($\lambda$).
>
> Derive the Cramer-Rao lower bound (CRLB) for the variance of any unbiased for estimator of $\lambda$.

I first set

$$L(\lambda) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\lambda^y e^{-\lambda}}{y!} = \frac{\lambda^{\prod_{i = 1}^n y_i} e^{-\lambda n}}{\prod_{i=1}^n y_i !} .$$

Then setting it to $\ln$ form:

$$\ln L(\lambda) = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i \ln(\lambda) - \lambda n}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} y_i !}.$$

Can anyone please confirm what I am doing is correct before I move forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likelihood function is
$$
L(\lambda)=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{y_i!}\right)\lambda^{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}e^{-\lambda n}
$$
and hence the log-likelihood function becomes
$$
l(\lambda)=-\lambda n+\log(\lambda)\sum_{i=1}^n y_i-\sum_{i=1}^n \log(y_i!).
$$

Comment: are the following correct? $$\frac{d ln L(\lambda)}{\lambda} = \frac{1}{\lambda} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i - n$$

$$\frac{d^2 ln L(\lambda)}{\lambda} = \frac{-1}{\lambda^2} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i $$

So $$E[\frac{-1}{\lambda^2} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i] = \frac{-1}{\lambda^2} n\bar{y}$$

Comment: The mean of $y_i$ is $\lambda$ not $y_i$ and hence the last is not correct.

Comment: For my last equation:

$$E\left[\frac{-1}{\lambda^2} \sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right] = \frac{-1}{\lambda^2} n \lambda = \frac{-n}{\lambda}$$. Therefore, the CRLB is $\frac{-\lambda}{n}$, right?

Comment: No, the Cramer-Rao lower bound for the _variance_ is certainly not negative. You're missing a minus-sign in the expression for the Fisher information.

Comment: so my answer is only off by a minus sign right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Do you know how to use this result to show that $\bar{Y}$ is the best unbiased estimator of $\lambda$?

Comment: If the best unbiased estimator means that it is unbiased and has minimal variance, then show that it is unbiased for $\lambda$ and that the variance is equal to the Cramer-Rao lower bound.

Comment: to show unbiased, $E(\bar{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^n y_i/n = n\lambda/n = \lambda$, right?

Comment: Replace $y_i$ by $E(y_i)$, then yes.

Comment: you mean to $E(\bar{y}) = \sum_{i=1}^n E(y_i/n) = n\lambda/n = \lambda$, right?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: what will $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ equal to then?

Comment: I am trying to calculate its variance$$V(\bar{y}) = V(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_i}{n}) = \frac{1}{n^2} [E(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)^2  - [E(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)^2]] $$is the setup right? If so, how to find $E(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)^2$? My approach is $$\frac{1}{n^2} [n\lambda^2 - n^2\lambda^2] = \frac{\lambda^2(1-n)}{n}$$, right?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i$ doesn't occur _anywhere_ in your calculations, only $\sum_{i=1}^n E(y_i)$ does which, of course, equals $n\lambda$. The variance of $\bar{y}$ is obtained by using that $V(y_i)=\lambda$ and that $V(aX)=a^2V(X)$. This should give you $\lambda/n$ which is the C-R lower bound. Note that these calculations of the mean and variance are _very_ basic, so maybe you should revisit your textbook.

Comment: Just want to make sure: to calculate $E(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)$, we have to first separate it $\sum_{i=1}^n E(y_i) $. Then $E(y_i) = \lambda$. Since there is a summation side, we have to multiply $\lambda$ by n. Is this the right way? This is the same reasoning for finding the variance, right?

Comment: Exactly @afsdfdfsaf. Although for the variance, we use the independence assumption to deduce that $V(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n V(y_i)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have one more question which is related to a biased estimator in another post. If you have time and interest, please take a look at the following link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/770802/show-that-s-sqrts2-is-a-biased-estimator-of-sigma-given-a-random-samp