# Show that $S = \sqrt{S^2}$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma$ given a random sample from a normal distribution ...

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ is a random sample from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Let $S^2$ be the sample variance, which is unbiased for $\sigma^2$.

GOAL: Show that $S = \sqrt{S^2}$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma$.

I realize that $(n-1)S^2/ \sigma ^2$ is chi-square with $(n-1)$ degrees of freedom.

I am given that $$E(S) = E\left[\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n-1}} \left[\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\right]^{1/2}\right] = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n-1}} \int_0^\infty v^{1/2} \frac{1}{\Gamma[(n-1)/2] 2^{(n-1)/2}} v^{(n-1)/2} e^{-v/2} \, dv$$

Can anyone help me understand why they have $v^{1/2}$ and $v^{(n-1)/2}$ (combining them $v^{n/2}$ as I think it should be $v^{1/2}$ and $v^{\frac{(n-1)}{2}-1}$ (combining both terms give $v^{(n-2)/2}$ since the pdf for chi-square distribution is $$ f(v) = \frac{v^{(x/2)-1} e^{-v/2}}{2^{x/2}\Gamma(x/2)},$$ where $x$ is degree of freedom?  Could anyone please tell me which one is the correct answer with explanation?

Thank you

Comment: I've deleted my answer; I'll do some further editing and then un-delete it.

Comment: It appears that what you say about the density function is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $x$ degrees of freedom, the chi-square distribution is
$$
f(v)\,dv = \left.\left(\frac v 2\right)^{x/2 - 1} e^{-v/2}\,\frac{dv}{2}\right/\Gamma\left(\frac x 2\right)
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty v^{1/2} f(v)\,dv & = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n-1}} \int_0^\infty v^{1/2} \left.\left(\frac v 2\right)^{(n-1)/2 - 1} e^{-v/2}\,\frac{dv}{2}\right/\Gamma\left(\frac {n-1} 2\right) \\[10pt]
& = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n-1}} \int_0^\infty 2^{1/2} \left.\left( \frac v 2 \right)^{(n-2)/2} e^{-v/2} \frac{dv}{2} \right/\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \\[10pt]
& = \sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}} \left. \int_0^\infty u^{n/2-1} e^{-u}\,du \right/\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right) \\[10pt]
& = \sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}} \cdot \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac n 2\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{n-1}{2}\right)}.
\end{align}

It remains to show that the factor by which $\sigma$ is multiplied is not $1$.  (Maybe I'll say more about that later.)

Comment: As long as I can show the things associated with $\sigma$ at your last equation is not 1, I have showed the estimator is biased right?

Comment: Correct. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It may help to recall that $\Gamma\left(\dfrac 1 2 \right)=\sqrt{\pi}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I just did a quick calculation for $\frac{\Gamma(n/2)}{\Gamma((n-1)/2)}$ by using WolframAlpha, the link listed below (the answer does not look like I can simplify though): https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Gamma%28n%2F2%29%2FGamma%28%28n-1%29%2F2%29

Comment: If I want to adjust S to form an unbiased estimator of $\sigma$, is it simply $$\hat{\sigma} = \frac{\sqrt(n-1) \Gamma[(n-1)/2]}{\sqrt(2) \Gamma(n/2)} S $$ and this is the unbiased for $\sigma$?

Comment: Yes, that will do it.  What's essential here is that the thing by which you're multiplying $S$ doesn't have "$\sigma$" in it anywhere (nor other unobservables, such as $\mu$).

Comment: still struggling for figuring out the thing associated with $\sigma$ is not equal to 1? Any comment on it?

Comment: Let's try $n=7$. We have  $\Gamma(7/2)=(5/2)(3/2)(1/2)\Gamma(1/2)$ $=(15/8)\sqrt{\pi}$, and $\Gamma(6/2)=2$.  Now let's try $n=8$. We have $\Gamma(8/2)= 6$ and $\Gamma(7/2) = (5/2)(3/2)(1/2)\sqrt{\pi}$.  We always have $\sqrt{\pi}$ in either the numerator or the denominator, and we're multiplying it by $\sqrt{2/(n-1)}$.  Can the product be shown to be irrational?

Answer (score 2):

You might think about this general situation Let $X,Y$ be two positive random variables such that $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\mathbb{E}(Y^2)$. Then, by Jensen inequality, 
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y)\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)}=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}
$$
 with equality if and only if $Y$ is deterministic. Thus, if $Y$ isn't deterministic, then
$$
\boxed{\mathbb{E}(Y^2)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)\Rightarrow \mathbb{E}(Y) < \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}.}
$$

Now in your case, take $X=Z-\mathbb{E}(Z)$ with $Z\sim {\cal N}(\mu,\sigma)$ and take $Y$ equal to $S$ (which is not deterministic). Applying the above inequality, we get 
$$
\mathbb{E}(S)<\sigma.
$$
In particular, $S$ is a biased estimator of $\sigma$.

Edit: I just realized that I answered the GOAL but not the actual question... Still,  it might help you for your homework!

Comment: I just edited my question. Please take a look to see if you can answer.